# Chat is saying I need 20 rep

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat, privileges

When I enter a lobby it says I need 20 reputation but I have 21 reputation what should I do? I tried logging in and out but it failed. I really want to talk with James and da peach please help.

Answer (score 7):

There can be a bit of a delay sometimes before rep propagates across the system. For example, here on Meta, you still have 11 rep right now. Give it a few minutes.

Comment: Ok thanks i will vote you

Comment: You don't need to announce your upvotes. In fact, it's discouraged.

Comment: @Stizzle84 - Also, you can 'accept' answers by clicking the checkmark under the vote count as well. This isn't required, but it does mean that the answer 'worked for you' :)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Why is it discouraged?

Comment: @JamesOfDaPeach anonymity is important to keep voting impartial and neutral.

Comment: @shanodin, James... not quite. While it's true that the *option* of anonymity is important -  particularly for downvotes - it isn't required that nobody ever announce their votes. It's just that doing so doesn't actually *communicate* anything. It's noise and clutter that doesn't actually serve to further the conversation and improve the internet. It's discouraged for the same reason we remove signatures and thank yous; because they take up space that could be used for and distract attention from *useful and informative content.*

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz that's why you won the diamond ;)